# shortest path in directed graph by selecting the strongest connected nodes at each level

Tags: graph, path

I am looking for an algorithm that finds a path between points A and B in a directed graph. The constraint is that is has to always try the edges with the highest cost first.
It is different than finding the shortest or longest path because this constraint has to be checked at every level.
 I will give an exemple: the first column are the  starting points and the second column are the  destination points:

- A C 8
- A D 5
- A E 2
- B A 1
- D A 5
- D B 1
- D E 3
- E B 2

The correct path from A to B would be:
A--5--> D --1--> B 
A to C was the first attempt, but since C is not connected to any other node it continued with the second option: A to D
D to A  was discarded because A is part of the current path (AD)
D to B is selected to minimize the path, although there is a another stronger connection between D and E.

So the contraints in order of importance are:
- shortest path
- strongest connection at each level

Thanks,
Cristi

Answer (score 0):

That's a modified Dijkstra's algorithm, with a per-step preference for heavy edges.

Comment: thanks, that i figured out myself already. however, i have tried to code this but i failed. now i'm looking for some already written code that works.

Comment: Then post what you've tried! There are literally thousands of Dijkstra implementations out there. I can't believe you can't modify a single one to your needs; if your programming skills are not up to that task, I'm afraid that sample code won't help you much :(